# Monkey Patching in Go show different result when running from CLI

Tags: unit-testing, go, monkeypatching

I am using Monkey Patching in Go. When I debug the following code in VSCode it shows that the function proc.Signal return the error programmed.

```
func TestCheckProcessRunning(t *testing.T) {
    monkey.Patch((*os.Process).Signal, func(p *os.Process, sig os.Signal) error {
        return errors.New("Signal failed")
    })
    proc := &os.Process{}
    sig_e := proc.Signal(syscall.Signal(0))
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", sig_e)

}
```

```
Signal failed
```

But when I tried to run the test using **go test .** , the patch is no longer applied and got a different error:

```
os: process not initialized
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you two feel like you needed to reply when I had already posted a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it needed the flag -gcflags=-l

```
go test -gcflags=-l .
```